# Dynamic (Column Based) Interval

Tags: postgresql

How do I add a dynamic (column based) number of days to NOW?

```
SELECT NOW() + INTERVAL a.number_of_days "DAYS" AS "The Future Date" 
FROM a;
```

Where `a.number_of_days` is an integer?

Answer (score 276, accepted):

I usually multiply the number by `interval '1 day'` or similar, e.g.:

```
select now() + interval '1 day' * a.number_of_days from a;
```

Comment: Nice trick, but it seems to me the better solutions are the ones below where they cast the concatenated field(s) to a interval, either using CAST or ::interval.

Comment: Why do you think it is a better solution @DeniseMeander?

Comment: Our team has agreed to implement this technique throughout a project because it is more human readable to declare the unit of the interval (`1 day`) then multiply that interval by our (sometimes convoluted) SQL arithmetic.  In some ugly cases with have a calculated interval inside of a calculated interval -- not nice.  With this implementation, I don't need to write `::INTERVAL` after appending `' DAYS'` to a calculated integer.

Answer (score 44):

I know this is a year old, but if you need to use a column to specify the actual interval (e.g. 'days', 'months', then it is worth knowing that you can also CAST your string to an Interval, giving:

```
SELECT now()+ CAST(the_duration||' '||the_interval AS Interval)
```

So the the original question would become:

```
SELECT now() + CAST(a.number_of_days||" DAYS" AS Interval) as "The Future Date" FROM a;
```

Comment: if you want more control over what the values in the units column would be, you can decode it yourself: `select *, num * case unit when 'W' then '1 week'::interval when 'D' then '1 day'::interval when 'H' then '1 hour'::interval end from (values(1,'W'),(2,'D'),(3,'H')) x(num, unit)`

Comment: thanks, that helped me a lot. But don't forget to change the quotation marks for postgres: `SELECT now() + CAST(a.number_of_days||' DAYS' AS Interval) as "The Future Date" FROM a;`

Comment: i tried to long to find out solution for this problem and in conclude i read this answer and  after try this, it worked correctly. thanks man

Answer (score 34):

I prefer this way. I think its pretty easy and clean.
In Postgres you need `interval` to use `+` operator with `timestamp`

```
select (3||' seconds')::interval;

select now()+ (10||' seconds')::interval,now();
```

where you can use seconds, minutes, days, months...
and you can replace the numbers to your column.

```
select now()+ (column_name||' seconds')::interval,now()
from your_table;
```

Answer (score 7):

Use `make_interval()`

```
SELECT NOW() + make_interval(days => a.number_of_days) AS "The Future Date" 
FROM a;
```

But in general it might be a better idea to use a column defined as `interval`, then you can use any unit you want when you store a value in there.

Comment: `days =>  a.number_of_days` appears to be Postgres' keyword syntax, and make_interval only has parameters for `years`, `months`, `weeks`, `days`, `hours`, `mins` and `secs`. That means it wouldn't work for all units like `interval '1 millisecond' * msTime` does, but it's still a fair alternative for most cases.

Comment: @VLRoyrenn: `secs` accepts a `double value` so if you want milliseconds use `secs => 0.001`

Answer (score 6):

To creating intervals those based on column values, I recommend to add two columns in your table. For example, column "period_value"::INT4 and column "period_name"::VARCHAR. 
Column "period_name" can store the following values:

- microsecond
- milliseconds
- second
- minute
- hour
- day
- week
- month
- quarter
- year
- decade
- century
- millennium

```
+--------------+-------------+
| period_value | period_name |
+--------------+-------------+
| 2            | minute      |
+--------------+-------------+
```

Now you can write:

```
SELECT NOW() - (period_value::TEXT || ' ' || period_name::TEXT)::INTERVAL FROM table;
```

Comment: You are essentially implementing the functionality that the data type `interval` already provides. Creating a single column of type `interval` would be a much better solution than this hack.

Answer (score 0):

If we have field with interval string value such as '41 years 11 mons 4 days' and want to convert it to date of birth use this query :

```
UPDATE "february14" set dob = date '2014/02/01'  - (patient_age::INTERVAL)
```

*dob* is date field to convert **'41 years 11 mons 4 days'**  to  **'1972/10/14'** for example 
*patient_age* is varchar field that have string like '41 years 11 mons 4 days'

And this is query to convert age back to date of birth

```
SELECT now() - INTERVAL '41 years 10 mons 10 days';
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating based on a column ID was a useful way to create some randomised test data for me.

```sql
update study_histories set last_seen_at = now() - interval '3 minutes' * id;
```