# Postgres INTERVAL using value from table

Tags: sql, postgresql

If I want to add 5 days to a date, I can do it using the `INTERVAL` function:

```
select create_ts + interval '5 days' from abc_company;
```

However, my table has a field called `num_of_days` and I want to add it to my create_ts. Something like this:

```
select create_ts + interval num_of_days || ' days' from abc_company;
```

This does not work. How can I accomplish this in postgresql?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamic (Column Based) Interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5266758/dynamic-column-based-interval)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Simply multiply the value with an interval:

```
select create_ts + num_of_day * interval '1' day 
from abc_company;
```

Since Postgres 9.4 this is easier done using the `make_interval()` [function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-datetime.html):

```
select create_ts + make_interval(days => num_of_day)
from abc_company;
```

Comment: Interesting.  I thought you had to use `interval '1 day'`.  I wonder why the string is needed at all in the expression.

Comment: @GordonLinoff `interval '1' day` is the way interval literals are specified in the SQL standard. `interval '1 day'` is a Postgres extension if I'm not mistaken

Answer (score 5):

You just need a working type cast. This kind is standard SQL.

```
select current_timestamp + cast((num_of_days || ' days') as interval)
from abc_company;
```

This is an alternative syntax, peculiar to PostgreSQL.

```
select current_timestamp + (num_of_days || ' days')::interval
from abc_company;
```

I prefer not trying to remember the third kind of type cast supported by PostgreSQL, which is the function-like syntax.

```
select current_timestamp + "interval" (num_of_days || ' days')
from abc_company;
```

Why? Because [some function names have to be quoted](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS); *interval* is one of them.

> Also, the names interval, time, and timestamp can only be used in this
>   fashion if they are double-quoted, because of syntactic conflicts.
>   Therefore, the use of the function-like cast syntax leads to
>   inconsistencies and should probably be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

here is a function that I use:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION DateAdd(diffType varchar(15), incrementValue int, inputDate timestamp) RETURNS timestamp AS $$
DECLARE
   YEAR_CONST Char(15) := 'year';
   MONTH_CONST Char(15) := 'month';
   WEEK_CONST Char(15) := 'week';
   DAY_CONST Char(15) := 'day';
   HOUR_CONST Char(15) := 'hour';

   dateTemp timestamp;
   intervals interval;
BEGIN
    IF lower($1) = lower(YEAR_CONST) THEN
        select cast(cast(incrementvalue as character varying) || ' year' as interval) into intervals;
    ELSEIF lower($1) = lower(MONTH_CONST) THEN
        select cast(cast(incrementvalue as character varying) || ' months' as interval) into intervals;
    ELSEIF lower($1) = lower(DAY_CONST) THEN
        select cast(cast(incrementvalue as character varying) || ' day' as interval) into intervals;
    ELSEIF lower($1) = lower(WEEK_CONST) THEN
        select cast(cast(incrementvalue as character varying) || ' week' as interval) into intervals;
    ELSEIF lower($1) = lower(HOUR_CONST) THEN
        select cast(cast(incrementvalue as character varying) || ' hour' as interval) into intervals;
    END IF;

   dateTemp := inputdate + intervals;

   RETURN dateTemp;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Used like so:

```
select dateadd('day', 3, current_timestamp);
```

It supports adding years, months, weeks, days, hours. More support could be added