# PostgreSQL: how to delete rows from a table older than 2 months?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-delete

I've the next data table:

| customer | category | date_column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | A | 2021/06/16 |
| 02 | B | 2021/04/15 |
| 03 | C | 2021/03/15 |

I would like to create query that would delete rows from this data table older than 2 months and here is my try:

```
DELETE * FROM schema.table
WHERE DATEADD(Month,2,date_column) < getdate()
```

By now I've been trying to use DATEADD to make it but seems that this function doesn't work in PostgreSQL. Could you hel me, guys?

This would be the desired output:

| customer | category | date_column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | A | 2021/06/16 |

Thanks by the way.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27080505/dateadd-equivalent-in-postgresql

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postgres INTERVAL using value from table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26979764/postgres-interval-using-value-from-table)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
DELETE * FROM schema.table
WHERE date_column < CURRENT_DATE - interval '2 month';
```

You can find the documentation [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html).

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @armanditoit was the easiest and clean way to make it :)