# Create interval using a column value postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query that's something like this

```
select days, date(date_event)  + interval '10' day from tbl_user_marketing_program as programtable
```

Now in place of the '10', I want to add the value present in the "days" column. How can I do that?

I tried `select user_id, date(date_event)  + interval user_id day from tbl_user_marketing_program as programtable`

then I got the below error

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "day"
>   LINE 1: ...ect user_id, date(date_event)  + interval user_id day from t...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamic (Column Based) Interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5266758/dynamic-column-based-interval)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Unfortunately the "number" for an interval can't be an arbitrary expression, it has to be a string constant (which is a strange choice). You need to use a little workaround:

```
select days, date(date_event) + (days * interval '1' day) 
from tbl_user_marketing_program as programtable
```

But `date + integer` is also directly supported and the unit is days in that case. So you can als write:

```
select days, date(date_event) + days 
from tbl_user_marketing_program as programtable
```

Answer (score 3):

You can quote `'10 days'`:

```
select days, date(date_event)  + interval '10 days'
from tbl_user_marketing_program as programtable
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/4287/0)**</kbd>

If you want add variable/column use:

> **datetime + variable * INTERVAL '1 day'**

```
select days, date(date_event)  + column * interval '1 day'
from tbl_user_marketing_program as programtable
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c5db1/2/0)**</kbd>

Comment: No, `interval '10' day` is correct - it's the way an interval literal is defined in the SQL standard and it **is** supported by Postgres

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I  misunderstood question. Anyway +1 for your answer

Answer (score 0):

If days column is integer, first cast it as interval type:

```
select days, date(date_event)  + cast(days as interval day(7))
from tbl_user_marketing_program as programtable
```

Comment: `cast(days as day(7))` is invalid

Comment: It is? How do you cast as interval types in Postgresql?

Comment: There is no function `day(x)` in SQL (or Postgres). See Lad's and my answer for a correct way to specify an interval

Comment: Oops, typo... Does cast(days as interval day(7)) work?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, casting to an interval is the solution (instead of useing `interval your_column days`)

```
select days, date(date_event)  + (user_id::integer || ' day')::interval from tbl_user_marketing_program as programtable
```

that converts the user_id to integer, concatenates with 'day', and casts the whole string to interval.  That interval you can add to your date.