# How correct transfer numeric variable from loop inside postgresql function

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-8.3

I work with PostgreSQL 8.3.23.
For  some cases I want to have table with values in the format YYYYMM as integer from last date month -1 month, -2 month, ...-6 month and I want automate routine with pqsql function.
I must enter only one number for example `202204` and get table with required values for further sub query.
Now i wrote this sub product

```
create or replace  function years_months ()  
returns table(id int4, year_month int4) 
language plpgsql as $$  
declare
   end_ym integer:=202204;
   bm_1 integer:=to_char(to_date(to_char(end_ym,'999999'),'YYYYMM')
    - interval '1 MONTH','YYYYMM')::int;
   bm_2 integer:=to_char(to_date(to_char(end_ym,'999999'),'YYYYMM')
    - interval '2 MONTH','YYYYMM')::int;
   bm_3 integer:=to_char(to_date(to_char(end_ym,'999999'),'YYYYMM')
    - interval '3 MONTH','YYYYMM')::int ;
   bm_4 integer:=to_char(to_date(to_char(end_ym,'999999'),'YYYYMM')
    - interval '4 MONTH','YYYYMM')::int ;
   bm_5 integer:=to_char(to_date(to_char(end_ym,'999999'),'YYYYMM')
    - interval '5 MONTH','YYYYMM')::int ;
   bm_6 integer:=to_char(to_date(to_char(end_ym,'999999'),'YYYYMM')
    - interval '6 MONTH','YYYYMM')::int;
begin
    drop table if exists last_ym;
    create table last_ym(
    id serial4 not null,
    year_month int4  not null ,
    constraint id primary key (id));
    create index idx_year_month on last_ym using btree (year_month);

    insert into last_ym(year_month) values
    (bm_1), (bm_2), (bm_3), (bm_4), (bm_5), (bm_6), (end_ym);
    
    return query 
        select 
            * 
        from 
            last_ym
        order by 
            year_month desc;
end $$;
```

when I run

```
select * from years_months ()
```

I get this output

```
id  year_month
7   202204
1   202203
2   202202
3   202201
4   202112
5   202111
6   202110
```

select * from last_ym show that table last_ym exits and ready for further work.

My questions

1. How I can using more elegant way with pqslq cycle **for bm in 1..7 loop** like this bellow

> ```
> do $$ 
> declare
>    end_ym integer:=202204;
> begin
>   drop table if exists last_ym;
>   create table last_ym(
>   id serial4 not null,
>   year_month int4  not null ,
>   constraint id primary key (id));
>     create index idx_year_month on last_ym using btree (year_month);  
>    for bm in 1..7 loop
>      if bm < 7 then 
>           insert into last_ym(year_month) values(
>           to_char(to_date(to_char(end_ym,'999999'),
>           'YYYYMM') - interval select'''bm MONTH'''||','|| '''YYYYMM''')::int);
>          else
>               insert into last_ym(year_month) values(end_ym);
>          end if;
>    end loop;
> end $$;
> ```

When I run this script I have this message in the console near **interval select'''bm MONTH'''**

> SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "select"   Position:
> 447
>
> Error position: line: 199 pos: 446

2. I want add to table new column - for exampe mo_num  char type, where mo_num automate get values last year_month minus month to last_ym table - like see bellow

   ```
   id  year_month mo_num
    7   202204      m_0
    1   202203      m_1
    2   202202      m_2
    3   202201      m_3 
    4   202112      m_4
    5   202111      m_5
    6   202110      m_6
   ```

Thanks in advance,
there is very little literature on pgsql.

Best regards, Vadim Maklakov.

Comment: "*I work with PostgreSQL 8.3.23*" - please upgrade, we're far out of the support lifetime for that version.

Comment: Are you using that table `last_ym` outside of this function? You really should not need that just to produce the result for the function!

Comment: `interval select'''bm MONTH'''` doesn't make sense. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/datatype-datetime.html#AEN4983 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/5266758/1048572

Comment: `please upgrade, we're far out of the support lifetime for that version.  Bergi`                                  I can't upgrade it because it is  the enterprise standard

Comment: `Are you using that table last_ym outside of this function? You really should not need that just to produce the result for the function!  – Bergi` Yes, table last_ym  will be using further in the middle complicate query

Comment: `interval select'''bm MONTH''' doesn't make sense. See postgresql.org/docs/8.3/datatype-datetime.html#AEN4983 and stackoverflow.com/q/5266758/1048572 – Bergi` if here i
 ago`bm_5 integer:=to_char(to_date(to_char(end_ym,'999999'),'YYYYMM')
  - interval '5 MONTH','YYYYMM')::int ; interval work correct hence it must work correct and in the for loop

Comment: "*table `last_ym` will be using further in the middle complicate query*" - what do you mean by "middle complicate query"? Why don't you just call your `years_month()` function instead of referring to that table?

Comment: `"table last_ym will be using further in the middle complicate query" - what do you mean by "middle complicate query"? Why don't you just call your years_month() function instead of referring to that table? ` - I don't want write mega function with variables because it's hard debug.  I want enter one integer in the function and get requred set of integer which I further use in the different part of middle complicated query through subquery to  last_ym. May be in the future I require 30 months or above - it is variable and isn't fixed interval  .

Comment: "*I don't want write mega function*" - that's not I was suggesting. "*I want enter one integer in the function*" - your function currently doesn't take any parameters? "*set of integer which I further use in the different part of middle complicated query through subquery to last_ym*" - this is still not clear. What subquery do you mean? Are you referring to `select * from last_ym order by year_month desc`? That's not a complicated query. If you are using `last_ym` anywhere outside of this function, please [edit] your question to include that code. Otherwise, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Forget all this procedural code. Forget the temporary table, the repeated variables, the drop and recreate, the unnecessary index, the insertions, and the query of the temporary table. You need none of this.

Write a plain simple [SQL function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html) that uses the [`generate_series` set-returning function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION years_months() RETURNS TABLE(id int4, year_month int4) 
LANGUAGE SQL
PARALLEL SAFE
ROWS 10
IMMUTABLE AS $$  
SELECT
   i,
   to_char(to_date(to_char(202204,'999999'),'YYYYMM') - i * interval '1 MONTH','YYYYMM')::int
FROM generate_series(0, 6) i;
$$;
```

<sup>([online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=be4bfa312fad1e89303ca775a31bc00d))</sup>

It does just the same as your original function, but much more efficiently and without all the ugly stateful code. You can also trivially add the `mo_num` column to it ([demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=83a6a50e27e793c360d928a13cc6ab15)).

Comment: Bergi, hi!  I am sorry because I was very busy on my work. Thank you very match for yours simple and elegant decision . This is exactly what I needed, thanks you very much again. Advise something to read or some resource on pgsql  functions - sometimes  there was a need to write sometimes simple functions on the server side. Best regards